# UIView block animation with completion handler and setting UIViews to hidden

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation, hidden, uigesturerecognizer

I'm keen on the new block animations in iOS 4. That is, the syntax

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction  animations:^
        {
              someview.alpha = 0

        } completion::^(BOOL finished) 
             {
                 focusAndExposureBox.hidden = true;
           }];
```

I have a case where I am using gesture recognizers and animating a view at the end of a gesture. I have a completion handler which sets someview to hidden (for performance reasons I need to do this). Often interaction is blocked due to the hidden property being set. My previous solution is to use the previous style of animation with an animationDidStop handler

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.25];
someview.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

However, I'd like to use the newer style if possible, because it has a cleaner method of performing actions after the animation finishes, and is recommended by Apple. So, currently I am using this hackery:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 
      options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

           someview.alpha = 0;

       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


[someview performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] afterDelay:1];

            }];
```

Does anyone know of a way to prevent blocking in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid the Blocking issue if you're using Gesture Recognizers with delegates, as the delegate function will be invoked independent of the main thread.

Comment: You are referring to gesture recognizer delegates, or something else?